# C# "If this, then don't execute this" - Is there such a thing?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
if (riflesRadio.Checked == true || smgsRadio.Checked == true || heavysRadio.Checked == true)
//then don't execute below
{
    if (secondaryList.Enabled == false)
    {
        secondary = "";
        secondarycost = 0;
    }

    if (heavyList.Enabled == false)
    {
        heavys = "";
        heavycost = 0;
    }

    if (primaryList.Enabled == false)
    {
        rifles = "";
        riflecost = 0;
    }

    if (smgList.Enabled == false)
    {
        smgs = "";
        smgcost = 0;
    }
}
//up to here
```

So basically, in my windows form, if these buttons are being checked, then don't execute the lines below.

I don't know if this is a possible solution, but here is a GIF example of what is wrong: http://i.imgur.com/bdX53Qc.gifv
After selecting the first item, it shows the pricing correctly. However, when I move to another radio to enable the other drop list, then enable the previous list, it shows the pricing as `0`. 
I know this is caused by the code I have pasted above, but what would be the solution to this?

thank you

Comment: This is some pretty basic boolean logic. If you have an `if (true) { do this }` and you want it to not do this if it's true, then you simply need to flip the boolean. IE `if (!true) { do this }`

Comment: Change your condition to `if (!riflesRadio.Checked && !smgsRadio.Checked  && !heavysRadio.Checked )`

Comment: if (!(riflesRadio.Checked == true || smgsRadio.Checked == true || heavysRadio.Checked == true))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just negate the bool, only execute if the condition is not true:

```
if( !(riflesRadio.Checked == true || smgsRadio.Checked == true || heavysRadio.Checked == true) )
{
    //...
}
```

Also, you can simplify you expression to:

```
if( !(riflesRadio.Checked || smgsRadio.Checked || heavysRadio.Checked ) )
```

Or:

```
if( !riflesRadio.Checked && !smgRadio.Checked && !heavysRadio.Checked )
```

Or:

```
bool noneChecked = !riflesRadio.Checked && !smgRadio.Checked && !heavysRadio.Checked;
if( noneChecked )
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. This wasn't the solution to my problem, but I didn't know about negating bools, so thanks again. I solved my issue by copying the whole switch statement from the event "SelectedIndexChanged" and pasted it into the radio "CheckedChanged" event. I first pasted it under all the other code in the raido event, which was the result of the gif. I cut and pasted the code at the start of the event, and it works like how i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply revert your `if` condition:

```
if (!riflesRadio.Checked && !smgsRadio.Checked && !heavysRadio.Checked)
// then execute below
{
    if (secondaryList.Enabled == false)
    {
        secondary = "";
        secondarycost = 0;
    }
    if (heavyList.Enabled == false)
    {
        heavys = "";
        heavycost = 0;
    }
    if (primaryList.Enabled == false)
    {
        rifles = "";
        riflecost = 0;
    }
    if (smgList.Enabled == false)
    {
        smgs = "";
        smgcost = 0;
    }
}
//up to here
```

So that from

> if any of these three values is `true`, then do not execute this

becomes

> only in case if all of these three values are `false`, execute this

Comment: Note that some people consider `if (boolVariable == true)` or `if (!boolVariable == false)` kind of redundant. Instead, you could just use `if (boolVariable)` or `if (!boolVariable)`

Comment: @Tom Oh, of course, I would never compare boolean in such manner. I just have tried to comply with the OP's code - to write in the same "style" to make it understandable.

Answer (score -4):

Break! 
Use break command to terminate the loop in case of an unfavourable event.

```
*if (this condition)
{
break;
}*
```

Comment: `break` stops `switch` or loop. If you mean `return`, then it will make execution of the code after `up to here` impossible.

Comment: And there is no indication he is in a loop

Comment: Usually, adding `break` statements is a sign of bad design. Not always, but usually. In this case, it is.